# CSSで ul を flex から block に書き換えたが、Chromeのモバイル表示で縦並びにならない

Tags: html, css

初心者で質問の要領も得ません。助けていただけたらありがたいです。

まず、HTMLでメニュー設定、次にCSSでメニューを横並びにする、さらに、モバイル用（幅が800px以下の場合）にはメニューを縦並びにする、ということをやりたい。

Chromeの「検証」のモバイル表示では字が小さくなって横並びのままです。しかし、普通の表示でウインドウを800px以下に縮めたら、縦に見えます。何がおかしいのでしょうか？

(追記)
いろいろ要領を得ず申し訳ございません。
いらないものが残っているかもしれませんが、以下、貼り付けてみました。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*ヘッダー*/
.header-inner {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle-menu-button {
  display: none;
}

.header-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
}

.site-menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.site-menu ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.site-menu ul li a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-title {
  font-family: 'Sawarabi Gothic', sans-serif;
}


/*フッター*/
.footer {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: hwb(0 0% 100% / 0.473);
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 235px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.footer-tel {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.copyright {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.sub-title {
  margin-top: 9px;
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
 
  .site-menu ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .site-menu li {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .header-inner {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .header-logo {
    width: 70px;
    height: 63px;
  }

  .header .site-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #736E62;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: none;
  }

 
  .toggle-menu-button {
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 34px;
    background-image: url(../images/home/bars_24.png);
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .toggle-menu-button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .site-menu.is-active {
    display: block;
  }


  .header-title {
    font-size: 80%;
  }

  .main {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }

  .first-view {
    height: 200px;
  }

  .footer-logo {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .footer-tel {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .copyright {
    margin-top: 45px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="大阪交野にある作文小論文・英語多読の専門教室">
  <title>NAKAO学習教室</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
  <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&family=Sawarabi+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-inner">
      <a class="header-logo" href="./index.html">
        <img src="#" alt="NAKAO学習教室">
      </a>
      <div class="header-title">
        <h1 class="title">学習教室</h1>
        <p class="sub-title">作文・小論文、英語多読の専門教室</p>
      </div>

      <button class="toggle-menu-button"></button>

      <div class="site-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="./about.html">教室について</a></li>
          <li><a href="./teacher.html">講師について</a></li>
          <li><a href="./guide.html">案内</a></li>
          <li><a href="./access.html">access</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&family=Oswald&family=Sawarabi+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </header>

  <main class="main">
    <div class="first-view">
      <div class="first-view-text">
      
      </div>
    </div>
 
   
  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="site-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about.html">教室について</a></li>
        <li><a href="./teacher.html">講師について</a></li>
        <li><a href="./guide.html">案内</a></li>
        <li><a href="./access.html">access</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="footer-logo" href="./index.html">
      <img src="#" alt="NAKAO学習教室">
    </a>
    <p class="footer-tel">TEL 000-0000-0000</p>
    <p class="copyright"><small>&copy;学習教室</small></p>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(".toggle-menu-button").click(function() {
    $(".site-menu").toggleClass("is-active");
  })
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)を参考に質問文を校正してください。少なくとも質問文を完成させてからタイトルを考えてください。

Comment: 残念ながら、現象の再現ができません。確認ですが、検証のモバイル表示のサイズは800以下になっていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。モバイルの設定は、「iPhon6/7/8 375✖️667」になっています。

Comment: やはり再現ができないようです。たとえば[codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/)のようなオンラインで確認できるツールを利用しても、現象は再現できないようです。もしかするとこれ以外のところに原因がある可能性があるので[再現可能な短いコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を作成してみてください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のように viewport の指定を追加してみてください。

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！　表示、正常になりました。感動です！